# Dynamically load from a properties file in java

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

I have a config.properties files with names like this:
    names=john,jane

Then I have a class that access that file and loads the names. And I have another class that get a name from somewhere and if that name is in the config.properties prints `"SUCCESS"`. The problem is that if I add names to the config.properties, I have to run again the program, it doesn´t load dynamically. What is the alternative to this?

```
 public class PropertiesFile {

    private static final char OPENFILES_CONFIG_DELIMITER = ',';
    private static final String OPENFILES_CONFIG = "config.properties";

    private static org.apache.commons.configuration2.Configuration config;

    static {
        try {
            Parameters params = new Parameters();
            FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> builder = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class)
                .configure(params.properties()
                    .setFileName(OPENFILES_CONFIG)
                    .setListDelimiterHandler(new DefaultListDelimiterHandler(OPENFILES_CONFIG_DELIMITER)));

            config = builder.getConfiguration();    } 
        catch (ConfigurationException cE) {
            //...
        }
    }

    public static Set<String> load() {
        String[] thingsToExecute = config.getStringArray("names");
        return new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(thingsToExecute));
    }

}



public class OpenFiles {

    private static Set<String> toExecute;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        updateToExecute();
        connect();
    }


    private static void connect() {

            //code that obatins JSONObject

            if (obj4.has("name")) {
                String personName = obj4.get("name").toString();
                updateToExecute();
                if (toExecute.contains(personName))   {                                              
                    System.out.println("SUCCESS");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(personName+"is not in the list");
                } 
            }
    }


    private static void updateToExecute() {
        toExecute = PropertiesFile.load();

    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation for reloading file configurations here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_reloading.html

Comment: yes, but still, doesn´t work

Comment: then paste the right code that uses file reloading, show us what you tried